# Android - PushBots: unregister device after uninstalling

Tags: android, notifications, push

I'm using PushBots for my application and noticed when I uninstall the app the device is still registered (on the PushBots site).

I've installed the app on 4 devices and uninstalled it on 3 of them.
But the Pushbots site says that there are still 4 devices.

Is it possible to unregister the device from PushBots when my application is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2):

here you go

```
Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(false);
Pushbots.getInstance().unregister(context);
```

https://pushbots.com/developer/gcm#g6